# How to identify duplicates in a unix file and sum up the values

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, uniq

I am trying to identify duplicates in a unix file and sum up the values .
For example:

I have a file like:

```
aa,  05
aa, 02
aa, 01
bb, 01
bb, 12
cc ,02
dd, 03
```

And I need the output:

```
aa, 08
bb, 13
cc, 02
dd,03
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' FS=, OFS=, file
bb,13
cc ,2
dd,3
aa,8
```

For custom sorting pipe to sort:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' FS=, OFS=, file | sort    
aa,8
bb,13
cc ,2
dd,3
```

See `man sort` for all the things `sort` can do.

If you want to clean the whitespace up around the commas then one method is:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' FS=' *, *' OFS=, file | sort 
aa,8
bb,13
cc,2
dd,3
```